# Having trouble centering a div class

Tags: css, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center the footer on a website but for some reason, the way I use that normally works won't work this time. Can anyone tell me why?

[Site is here](http://playdates.b.vhost.feynman.net/)

It's set up using two classes, one inside the other

First one is called mainFoot:

```
.mainFoot {
background-color: #184879;
width: 100%;
height: 60px; /*had to include this because it would not appear otherwise. browser read it as a 0 height container*/
display: block;
clear: both;
}
```

Second is page-footer:

```
#page-footer {
width: 990px;
display: block;
clear: both;
margin:0 auto;}
```

I was using the same structure right above it for the bottom widgets and it worked as is, but for some reason, while i was setting this one up, I had to set a height property for the outer div to appear as it wouldn't read the inner div's height and adjust.

For reference, he similar set up I mentioned that DOES work is right above the mainFoot class and is controlled by the classes b4Foot and half-widgets:

```
.b4Foot {
background-color: #277bc1;
width: 100%;
display: block;
clear: both;
}

.half-widgets {
width: 990px;
min-height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: A HTML code will be helpful along with this or jsfiddle link...

Comment: what is the surrounding situation? percent width & height only work with static parent elements. and what the hell is with these photos in footer?

Comment: [class*="span"] this bootstrap css has float left. make footer.span12 float none

Answer (score 0):

To center the contents of a block, you need to set the style "text-align:center". However, note that you cannot center a block-type element within another block-type element. The inner element needs to have the display style of inline or inline-block.

To fix your problem, you need to: a) remove the fixed width, and b) change page-footer to display:inline-block. Currently it is display:table because of the class clearfix - you need to remove that class fromt he div.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change just this line please see below and put on your CSS and see result

```
.mainFoot
{
    background-color:#184879 !important;
    height:60px;
    width:auto;
}
footer.span12 { color:#DEDEDE; width:100%;}
#page-footer { display:block; margin:0 auto; width:990px;}
```

only change on .mainFoot , footer.span12 and #page-footer

Thanks,